# Simplepie includes phantom enclosures that don't exist

Tags: php, simplepie

I am combining two feeds, with enclosures, and items that don't have enclosures are showing up with empty enclosures.

Here's the code with the offending bit in bold:

```
<item>
<title><?echo $item->get_title(); ?></title>
<guid><? echo $item->get_permalink(); ?></guid>
<link><? echo $item->get_permalink(); ?></link>
**<? if ($enclosure = $item->get_enclosure()) {echo "<enclosure url='"
.$enclosure->get_link() ."' length='" .$enclosure->get_length() ."' type='"
.$enclosure->get_type() ."' />";} ?>**
<description>
<? echo $item->get_title(); ?>
</description>
</item>
```

Items with no enclosures show up with an empty enclosure url, length, and type:

All real enclosures show up as they should with url, length and type.  I read a few threads on the Simplepie support page, but came up with no solution.

Thanks!

Comment: What does `$item->get_enclosure()` return if there is no enclosure?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Simplepie, but looking at the code, `$item->get_enclosure()` probably returns an object that evaluates to `true`, but is empty. So maybe you should change the condition of the `if` to:

```
<? $enclosure = $item->get_enclosure(); if ($enclosure->get_link()) {...
```